# SlimPHP Callable does not exist

Tags: php, slim

I have an api using the Slim framework (version 3).  The project structure has an api directory in the root directory.  In it I have dirs for "controllers", "models", "public", "src", etc., as well as my composer.json and vendor (once running composer install).  My controllers all have the namespace "App\Controllers" and the composer.json has

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": ""
}
```

defined in autoload.  While hitting a route, I am calling my controllers (ex. App\Controllers\AccountController:login).  All of this works fine in my vagrant environment, but as soon as I upload it to my production server (shared host and I dropped the entire api dir from my local environment to the public_html dir in the shared host), I get

> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Callable App\Controllers\AccountController does not exist
>
> File: /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
>
> Line: 62
>
> #0 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolverAwareTrait.php(45): Slim\CallableResolver->resolve('App\Controllers...')
>
> #1 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(314): Slim\Routable->resolveCallable('App\Controllers...')
>
> #2 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> #3 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(297): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> #4 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(441): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> #5 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> #6 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(337): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> #7 /home/downunde/public_html/api/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(298): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
>
> #8 /home/downunde/public_html/api/public/index.php(52): Slim\App->run()
>
> #9 {main}

Both servers are apache, PHP v. 5.6.  I confirmed it is properly hitting the route, but on the shared host it cannot find my controllers.

Comment: Have you run `composer install` on the server where it doesn't work?

Comment: I cannot install composer with my shared hosting provider.

Answer (score 7):

you should edit your `composer.json` like that:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": ""
    }
},
"require": {
    // ...
},
"scripts": {
    // ...
}
```

and `dependencies.php`

```
// PagesController
$container['PagesController'] = function ($container)
{
    return new \App\Controller\PagesController; 
};
```

next, you update your autoload

`$ composer dump-autoload -o`

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 3):

Probabily it's a case problem. If locally you are on windows remember that you are case-insensitive.

When you are on Linux you get a case-sensitive environment.

Case problem with Windows-Linux are a common problem. Try to use vagrant or any other approach to have the same environment both local and non-local.

Comment: I am on a Mac running on a vagrant image (using the vaprobash box).

Answer (score 2):

It was due to case sensitivity.  Not sure why it worked locally but not on the shared host.

Comment: Some how I had an extra space in my case :-P